# Google Maps v3 breaks Safari 5.0.5 Mac OS X font rendering

Tags: macos, google-maps, safari

When I embed a Google map into a web page and view it in Safari 5 on Mac all fonts before the map widget are ok, but fonts after seem to loose antialiasing and look ugly. Does anybody bumped into such thing? How can one fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you should file a bug report

Comment: Can you show us some example code? I haven't seen this issue when using Google Maps and Safari.

Comment: Did you find a solution. I just hit a similar bug.  Safari only, chrome is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying

```
.map{
    -webkit-transform:none;
     z-index:10;
}
```

to the google map div/frame

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. The elements you're applying cufon on cannot be position:absolute;
It's also a Safari 5 OSX specific bug.